# jQuery Expand/Collapse table row not showing when expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue I am having is on the 2nd level when there is a parent for a 3rd level child anything after it on the second level doesn't appear as it gets a "display:none" property instead of block.

Have created a JSfiddle showing the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/du6oy7oy/4/

If you open the first Parent Page you can see Parent Page 2, there is also another page after it titled Page Not Showing, it is the same level as Parent Page 2 so it should be showing.

I cannot figure out what is causing it

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function getChildren($row) {
    var children = [], level = $row.attr('data-level');
    while($row.next().attr('data-level') > level) {
         children.push($row.next());
         $row = $row.next();
    }            
    return children;
} 
function getChildrenOpen($row) {
    var children = [], level = $row.attr('data-level');
    level++;
    while($row.next().attr('data-level') == level) {
         children.push($row.next());
         $row = $row.next();
    }            
    return children;
}
$(document).on('click','.closed', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('closed');
    $(this).addClass('parent');
    $(this).find(".fatoggle").removeClass('fa-plus');
    $(this).find(".fatoggle").addClass('fa-minus');
    $(this).find(".btntoggle").removeClass('btn-primary');
    $(this).find(".btntoggle").addClass('btn-danger');
    var children = getChildrenOpen($(this));
    $.each(children, function() {
        $(this).css('display','table-row');
    })
});
$(document).on('click','.parent', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('parent');
    $(this).addClass('closed');
    $(this).find(".fatoggle").addClass('fa-plus');
    $(this).find(".fatoggle").removeClass('fa-minus');
    $(this).find(".btntoggle").addClass('btn-primary');
    $(this).find(".btntoggle").removeClass('btn-danger');
    var children = getChildren($(this));
    $.each(children, function() {
        $(this).css('display','none');
        $(this).removeClass('parent');
        $(this).addClass('closed');
        $(this).find(".fatoggle").addClass('fa-plus');
        $(this).find(".fatoggle").removeClass('fa-minus');
        $(this).find(".btntoggle").addClass('btn-primary');
        $(this).find(".btntoggle").removeClass('btn-danger');
    })
});
$(document).on('click','.parent a, .closed a',function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
});});
```

Simple Text Hierarchy:

- Page
- Parent Page

  - Page
  - Page
  - Parent Page 2

    - Page
  - Page Not Showing
- Page
- Parent Page

  - Page
  - Page

Comment: Your code is setup to stop as soon as it hits a level the same as the one clicked. Your "Page not showing" has a `data-level="1"` so it stops as the intended parent also has a level of `1`. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function to open the children only iterates across elements at the exact level. This means it hits your level 2 and stops before it hits the level 1.

```
function getChildrenOpen($row) {
  var children = [],
    level = $row.attr('data-level');
  level++;
  while ($row.next().attr('data-level') >= level) {
    if ($row.next().attr('data-level') == level) {
      children.push($row.next());
    }
    $row = $row.next();
  }
  return children;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/du6oy7oy/6/

Comment: Thanks for the help with reducing the code.
The problem is that the Page Not Showing should be the same level as the Parent Page 2 and shouldnt be inside that parent. But i still need to reflect the menu structure so I cannot place it before the Parent Page 2

Comment: Can you please add a simple text hierarchy of what belongs inside what? Just use indenting to show the intended structure.

Comment: Have added a hierarchy

Comment: I see the problem now. Your two functions are not the opposite of each other. The second one aborts early as it hits a child element. Give me a few mins to update example.